# Calling another method after response from subscribe()

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to execute some logic after getting a response from my `http get request`; ideally replacing the `.then()` which is not a method of type observable and everything that follows. Any help is appreciated.

```
// Getting app version
    this.http.get('assets/appversion.json').subscribe((version) => {
        runningVersion = version.data.version;

        const data = {
            mobileVersion: version.data.version,
            wsfunction: 'get_mobile_versioning',
            moodlewsrestformat : 'json'
        };

        const config = {
            params: data,
            headers : {'Accept' : 'application/json',
            }
        };

        return this.http.get
        (url, config);
    }).then((data) => { //RUN LOGIC AFTER RESPONSE FROM HTTP GET
        data.data.data.forEach((element) => {
            allowedVersionArray.push(element.allowed_versions);
        });

        allowedVersionArray.forEach((allowedVersion) => {
            if (allowedVersion === runningVersion) {
                isAllowedToRunApp = true;
            } else {
                // Redirect to allowed version app
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: you mean using `.subscribe` instead of `.then` ?

Comment: yes, im trying to get something to replicate the .then behavior @JacopoSciampi

Comment: You can call it form `subscribe` also

Comment: @DanielRM then just use it, it will run in async after that change. Be aware of this

Comment: @JacopoSciampi i think we have a misunderstanding, i have another httpcall inside my subscribe, which would require me to have another call back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the 2nd subscribe from within the first one. Ideally, you should create named functions to keep the code clearer and more maintainable, but this should work:

```
this.http.get('assets/appversion.json').subscribe(processVersion);

// Getting app version
function processVersion(version){
  runningVersion = version.data.version;

  const data = {
      mobileVersion: version.data.version,
      wsfunction: 'get_mobile_versioning',
      moodlewsrestformat : 'json'
  };

  const config = {
      params: data,
      headers : {'Accept' : 'application/json',
      }
  };

  this.http.get(url, config).subscribe(processData);
}

function processData(data){
  data.data.data.forEach((element) => {
    allowedVersionArray.push(element.allowed_versions);
  });

  allowedVersionArray.forEach((allowedVersion) => {
    if (allowedVersion === runningVersion) {
        isAllowedToRunApp = true;
    } else {
        // Redirect to allowed version app
    }
  });
}
```

You should also remember to always handle errors:

```
this.http.get('assets/appversion.json').subscribe(processVersion, errorOccurred);

// Getting app version
function processVersion(version){
  runningVersion = version.data.version;

  const data = {
      mobileVersion: version.data.version,
      wsfunction: 'get_mobile_versioning',
      moodlewsrestformat : 'json'
  };

  const config = {
      params: data,
      headers : {'Accept' : 'application/json',
      }
  };

  this.http.get(url, config).subscribe(processData, errorOccurred);
}

function processData(data){
  data.data.data.forEach((element) => {
    allowedVersionArray.push(element.allowed_versions);
  });

  allowedVersionArray.forEach((allowedVersion) => {
    if (allowedVersion === runningVersion) {
        isAllowedToRunApp = true;
    } else {
        // Redirect to allowed version app
    }
  });
}

function errorOccurred(error){
  throw `oh no! ${error} occurred!`;
}
```

Comment: Merci beaucoup!!

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `switchMap` operator like so:

```
this.http.get('assets/appversion.json').pipe(
  switchMap(version) => {
    runningVersion = version.data.version;

    const data = {
      mobileVersion: version.data.version,
      wsfunction: 'get_mobile_versioning',
      moodlewsrestformat : 'json'
    };

    const config = {
      params: data,
      headers : {'Accept' : 'application/json' }
    }

    return this.http.get(url, config);
  }).subscribe(
    (data) => { //RUN LOGIC AFTER RESPONSE FROM HTTP GET
      data.data.data.forEach((element) => {
        allowedVersionArray.push(element.allowed_versions);
      });

      allowedVersionArray.forEach((allowedVersion) => {
        if (allowedVersion === runningVersion) {
            isAllowedToRunApp = true;
        } else {
            // Redirect to allowed version app
        }
      });
  });
```